# Vue JS pass prop to route string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to pass prop into the link that I navigate to:

```
<v-btn router :to="/main/+{{siteType}}">

export default {
  props: ["siteType"]
}
```

How can I pass siteType prop to the link string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a computed property to it instead, because you cannot use mustache inside attributes, [as per documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes):

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a `v-bind` directive

Example:

```
<v-btn router :to="myCustomLink">

export default {
  props: ["siteType"],
  computed: {
    myCustomLink: function() {
      return `/main/${this.siteType}`,
    }
  }
}
```